# Bind DataGrid Columns to list

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm developing a WPF app based on MVVM. I want to bind a list of strings to column header ie., if the list contains "abc", "xyz", "pqr", then my `DataGrid` should have three columns with header abc, xyz, pqr. Here is my class to which I am binding the datagrid. The rows are stored in `ObservableCollection<List<string>>` where each element of `ObservableCollection` is a List of string which forms the cells of the rows.

```
public class Resource
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> columns;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Columns
    {
        get
        {
            return columns;
        }
        set
        {
            columns = value;
        }

    }

    private ObservableCollection<List<string>> row;
    public ObservableCollection<List<string>> Row
    {
        get
        {
            return row;
        }
        set
        {
            row = value;
        }
    }

    public Resource()
    {
        List<string> a = new List<string>();
        a.Add("1");
        a.Add("2");
        List<string> b = new List<string>();
        b.Add("11");
        b.Add("21");
        Row = new ObservableCollection<List<string>>();
        Row.Add(a);
        Row.Add(b);

        Columns = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Columns.Add("Hello");
        Columns.Add("World");
    }
}
```

I have searched Internet a lot but couldn't find anything with a working example. I really need to bind `DataGrid` by this method only.

Comment: Do you want to be able to reorder the columns?

Comment: @Markus I need to sort per column but not reorder

Comment: In my experience, even though it is doable using attached properties, this approach is too cumbersome and too limiting, and forces you to move to procedural code UI-specific things that should really be done in XAML. Use a specific XAML-defined `DataTemplate` per data-type instead of trying a "one size fits all" solution that won't really be suitable for anything but the very basic string-only data types.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the DataGrid in one of two ways :

1) Bind the DataGrid's ItemsSource to a Collection of elements which Expose 3 properties abc , xyz , pqr.

CS :

```
    public List<MyDataItem> DataItems 
    {
        get
        {
            List<MyDataItem> items = new List<MyDataItem>(5);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                items.Add(new MyDataItem { abc = abc[i], qrt = qrt[i], xyz = xyz[i] });
            }

            return items;
        }
    }

    int[] abc = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] qrt = new int[5] { 6,7,8,9,10 };
    int[] xyz = new int[5] { 11,12,13,14,15};


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

}

public class MyDataItem
{
    public int abc { get; set; }
    public int qrt { get; set; }
    public int xyz { get; set; }
}
```

XAML :

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}" />
```

2) Create a DataTable object and Bind it to your ItemsSource.

```
 public DataTable DataTable
    {
        get
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            table.Columns.Add("abc");
            table.Columns.Add("qrt");
            table.Columns.Add("xyz");

            table.Rows.Add(1, 6, 11);
            table.Rows.Add(2, 7, 12);
            table.Rows.Add(3, 8, 13);
            table.Rows.Add(4, 9, 14);
            table.Rows.Add(5, 10, 15);

            return table;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answers the question, it's not depending on `Columns` because `MyDataItem` contains a fixed number of properties and doesn't depends on `Columns ObservableCollection<string>`.